# Is it possible to do partial index on Apache Solr 4?

Tags: java, search, solr, solr4

We have around 5 projects which use one API for Products(Categories, Brands are also stored there).

But each project has it's own range of products, for example project1 can have ipod 4, iphone 5 as products list, project2 {ipod 4, iphone 4, macbook, das keyboard}.

Now idea is whenever someone searches for "ip" in project1 web-site it should return {'ipod 4', 'iphone 5'}, if search query is 'macbook' empty set will be returned.

But in case if someone will be searching for "macbook" in project2 website it will return {'macbook'}

So question is, how to do that using Apache Solr 4? Any ideas would be much more appreciated

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Not sure but is multi core in solr will helps you?

Comment: @Zero Can u tell me how multi-core configuration can help me?

Comment: You can have saparate core for each project,lets say core0 for project1 and it contains ipod4 & ipod5 only and core1 for proj2 and it contains macbook also along with ipods so this time you can easily search

Comment: @Zero Can you provide code of configs?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by having a multiple cores for each of your project data.
You can have reference for configuring multi core check this [Multi cor Config Solr](http://www.arunchinnachamy.com/apache-solr-installation-and-configuration/)

Comment: I know how to configure simple cores in Solr, but how would I route these requests coming from project1 to appropriate core? And how to create core with "partial" index?

Comment: If you can find out the request is for which project then you can simply send the request to the respective core by mentioning the core name in the query url http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=product:*